# IntelliJ - how to add maven framework to a scala project

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

I've created a simple hello world project and have a scala object created in the source directory.

My question. How do I correctly add a maven framework pom file to the proejct?

I want to try this example http://lollyrock.com/articles/scala-http-requests/

but I need to add the maven dependency for the "Dispatch library" to a pom file.

I have tried right clicking on project name > add framework support > select maven. But when I do this, I can no longer create a scala class, the only options are to create a scala worksheet and scala script.

Thank you

Comment: I repeated your steps and now I see `Scala class` just under `Java class` at menu `New`

Comment: Use sbt http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/index.html, it supports maven repositories